# Short story with "sky" in the title

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story in which people know only a virtual existence in separate underground cells. In the ending, perhaps because a real war is waging on the earth's surface, the narrator's cell is bombed or somehow torn open and they see the real sky for the first time. The word "sky" is in the title.

Comment: Some additional information would help a lot -- where/when did you read the story, in what language, was it in a collection or magazine?  Any additional plot details would also help in identifying the story.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like The Machine Stops https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops It had the cells in it. It ends "the whole city was broken like a honeycomb...for a moment they saw...scraps of the untainted sky." Posting as comment because it fails the "word sky in the title" test.